# Bypassing Proxy for Azure App Insights in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, azure, proxy, azure-application-insights

I am trying to implement App Insights for my Spring Boot Application. I am deploying the app using helm and K8S cluster.

The problem I am getting is to connect to Azure. It is trying to use the proxy that other items in the application needs. But I need to bypass the proxy for App Insights. My logs look something like:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.nexus.svct.local -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|windows.net|cluster.local|*.azure.com|*.azurecr.io|*.microsoftonline.com" -Dhttps.nonProxyHosts="windows.net|cluster.local*.azure.com|*.azurecr.io|*.microsoftonline.com" -Dapplicationinsights.runtime-attach.configuration.classpath.file=app_insights/api_access_app_insights_dev.json
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
2023-09-28 12:42:27.286Z INFO  c.m.applicationinsights.agent - Application Insights Java Agent 3.4.14 started successfully (PID 1, JVM running for 3.456 s)
2023-09-28 12:42:27.296Z INFO  c.m.applicationinsights.agent - Java version: 17.0.6, vendor: Oracle Corporation, home: /usr/local/jdk-17.0.6

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.2)

2023-09-28 12:42:28.408  INFO 1 --- [           main] io.swagger.Swag2SpringBoot            : Starting Swag2SpringBoot using Java 17.0.6 on swag-app-d1c-v2-5dd5b464bd-fl74n with PID 1 (/app/classes started by app in /)
2023-09-28 12:42:28.424  INFO 1 --- [           main] io.swagger.Swag2SpringBoot            : The following profiles are active: logjson,kube,oracle
2023-09-28 12:42:31.406  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-09-28 12:42:31.431  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-09-28 12:42:31.431  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.48]
2023-09-28 12:42:31.579  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/swag-app]      : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-09-28 12:42:31.579  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3083 ms
2023-09-28 12:42:32.062  INFO 1 --- [           main] i.m.c.instrument.push.PushMeterRegistry  : publishing metrics for AzureMonitorMeterRegistry every 1m
2023-09-28 12:42:33.467  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2023-09-28 12:42:34.761  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/swag-app'
2023-09-28 12:42:36.097  INFO 1 --- [           main] io.swagger.Swag2SpringBoot            : Started Swag2SpringBoot in 8.399 seconds (JVM running for 12.268)
2023-09-28 12:43:22.130  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/swag-app]    : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-09-28 12:43:22.130  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-09-28 12:43:22.132  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2023-09-28 12:43:31.331Z ERROR c.azure.core.http.policy.RetryPolicy - {"az.sdk.message":"Retry attempts have been exhausted.","exception":"http, none, proxy.nexus.svct.local/172.16.253.84:3128 => /169.254.169.254:80, status: 403 Forbidden","tryCount":3}
```

Somehow it is picking up the `-Dhttps.proxyHost` value and not the `-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts` or `-Dhttps.nonProxyHosts` value for App Insights. These values are configured in the helm charts.

Can you please help me with some pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fiddling with the configuration and I was able to get it to work by adding the IP `169.254.169.254` to nonProxy settings.

```
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|windows.net|cluster.local|*.azure.com|*.azurecr.io|*.microsoftonline.com|169.254.169.254"
```

If anyone has a better answer, please feel free to answer.